Process called lsof using too much CPU
I keep having
lsof -w -l +d /var/lib/php5

eating up my CPU
I want to know who is triggering it and what does it have with php5 ...

Is there a /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean script on your system? Why did /usr/lib/php5/sessionclean run 50 times simultaneously on my 14.04 system? is a question from 2014 which suggests lsof -w -l +d /var/lib/php5 can be run as part of PHP session cleanup.

@ChesterGillon no, there is not a folder nor a symlink or file called php5 in /var/lib folder...

pstree "$(pidof -s lsof)" should give you some informaton on who created that process. If you're using htop to observe CPU usage, in default configuration, the F5 key can be used to display processes and their parent processes as tree structure; maybe that helps.

but looking for an ancient installation of PHP: Unless you recently tried to install an old PHP thing, that would be a bit of a malware pattern, but that's not a sure thing; this might also just be a misled cleanup script from something else.

yes, smells like malware, I'll check what's going on on that machine...

I am not sure if I should write this as an answer, eventually
running htop, helped me figure out that there is a docker image
containing php5, which was starting automatically with system.

See https://github.com/yufongg/yufongg.github.io/blob/2954947eeb3df02ab284b198af331c705a89a786/_posts/Writeups/Vulnhub/Linux/Digitalworld.local%20(MERCY%20v2)/2022-02-08-Digitalworld.local%20(MERCY%20v2).md?plain=1#L857 (found by looking at the command in github)

lsof, (LiSt Open Files, see man lsof) is being run repeatedly, to check /var/lib/php5, and probably is part of a poorly written spin-lock.
Sub-minute repeated executions are often done by the watch command, but as a previous commenter says, pstree "$(pidof -s lsof)" is a good start.
If you have installed/removed/messed with PHP versions, you may have confused your syatem. If this is the case, use the AskUbuntu Search bar. Other users have had this problem, and may have solutions.
